# Wordpress switch domains

Tags: wp-admin, urls, site-url

So i am using cpanel on my website and i have `public.html/site.com` folder and there was one wordpress installed. I created subdomain `test.site.com` which root was in `publilc.html/test` and i have created site there and now i want to transfer it to `site.com`. I have 2 problems now.

First is that i do not know how to do it because i tried a lot of things and nothing worked.

Second is that while trying, i broke `test` site and now i can access it but half way. By that i mean i can access `wp-admin` and login but when i go `test.site.com` it redirects me to `site.com`. This happened when i went to test site setting through wp-admin, and changed site and site url to `site.com`, and then i couldn't even access wp-admin but then i went directly to database and changed it back to `test.site.com` and as i said now i can access wp-admin but it stills redirect me.

Here are my cpanel subdomains:

[image: subdomains]

Here are domains:

[image: domains]

If you need anything else please note me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, go to `phpMyAdmin`, go to your database for `test.site.com` and edit `siteurl` and/or `home` in `wp_options` table. That'll fix your `test.site.com`

Now, to migrate `test.site.com` to `site.com`, as you've difficulties doing it manually, I'd suggest a plugin like [Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) or [All-in-One WP Migration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/) to migrate the site. It's way easier that way.

To do the migration manually

1). In `phpMyAdmin`, your database of `test.site.com` to another database. [Here' how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16510615/1160699).

2). Replace all URL instances of `test.site.com` with `site.com`. Run the following query in your new copied DB

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://test.example.com', 'http://example.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://test.example.com','http://example.com');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://test.example.com', 'http://example.com');
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://test.example.com','http://example.com');
```

3). Now, move all files from `public_html/test` to `public_html/site`.

4). Lastly, change database details to the new copied database in `wp-config.php`